What does "super fast charging" exactly mean with Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra?
I use a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra. Sometimes, Android lock screen says "super fast charging". What does that exactly mean? I.e., how fast much charging be to be called "super fast"?

Samsung's devices show "super fast charging" when charged in certain conditions: 45W adaptive fast charging USB cable + 45W USB PD PPS charger.
According to Samsung UK - How to use Super fast charging,

What charger and cable are needed
Galaxy S22 and Galaxy S23 devices support fast, super fast, and wireless charging.
To use fast charging, a charging cable is required that supports adaptive fast charging with a capacity of 25W for Galaxy S22/S23 (battery capacity 3700mAh) and 45W for the Galaxy S22+/S23+ and Galaxy S22/S23 Ultra (battery capacity 4500-5000mAh).
To use super-fast charging, a charging cable that supports adaptive fast charging with a capacity of 45W is required - 45W TA + 5A cable (E-marked). You will also need a 45W Travel Adapter. Super fast charging cannot be performed using standard chargers. We recommend using the USB Type-C, 5A charging cable that comes with the 45W charger.

(Emphasis added)
Android Authority - What is Samsung Super Fast Charging and how fast is it? explains more about the technology, that Samsung has supported Super Fast Charging since Samsung Galaxy S10 5G (2019) though only up to 25W, until Galaxy Note 10 Plus started supporting up to 45W.

The Galaxy S10 5G from 2019 was Samsung’s first smartphone to offer Super Fast Charging, with support for up to 25W of power. The company one-upped itself a few months later with the Galaxy Note 10 Plus, which debuted with even faster 45W charging.

Also, while Samsung recommends its 45W Travel Adapter, any 45W USB PD PPS charger can be used, which is also an advantage compared to other manufacturers implementing their own proprietary standards.

[...] Samsung has one key advantage over the competition — it’s built upon the universal USB Power Delivery standard. This means you can use the same adapter to fast charge your smartphone, laptop, and tablet — even if they’re all made by different manufacturers.
In fact, Samsung’s Super Fast Charging is based on the newer USB PD Programmable Power Supply (PPS) standard. In a nutshell, PPS enables your device to communicate and negotiate the optimal power output with the adapter in real-time.
[...] OPPO’s SuperVOOC and Xiaomi’s HyperCharge technologies can both achieve upwards of 100W already. However, these are proprietary standards that require you to use manufacturer-specific adapters.

